# Everytime i restart the app, it displays the login page, even when there is user data (flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-signin

As the title suggests, im only using **signInWithGoogle()** for my user auth, each time i restart the app it went to Login Page even when the user did not log out.

I know this question has been asked plenty of times, im seeing many answers pointing towards using FirebaseAuth streambuilders but i cant seem to get it to work ... Sorry im a beginner and i do not understand much of the documentations too :(

Is there anyway i can direct the users that are logged in to the main page, and those without user data will have to visit LoginPage first?

sign_in.dart :

```
import 'package:confApp/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as fauth;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String name;
String email;
String imageUrlGoogle;
String id;

final fauth.FirebaseAuth _auth = fauth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<bool> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final fauth.AuthCredential credential = fauth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final fauth.UserCredential authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final fauth.User user = authResult.user;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);
  assert(user.photoURL != null);
  assert(user.uid != null);

  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  imageUrlGoogle = user.photoURL;
  id = user.uid;

  final fauth.User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  if ( fauth.FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
    return true;
  } else
    return false;

  // return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

Let me know what other codes that you need, ill update the question with the codes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before you continue looking for the error, I suggest updating to the latest version of your packages, some functions you use here are outdated.

Comment: @nvoigt honestly... all i did was following tutorials, ill take a look. Thanks!

Comment: There has been a recent breaking change, that will likely change how you build this function, so before you fix this and *then* change it all, better change it all first and then make it work :)

Comment: @nvoigt i have updated the codes to the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SharedPreference [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save user data. check this package you will know how to handle this. Basically you need to save user data by sharedPref, and retrieve while entering in the app and check if the user data is there you can route to user page, if no user data route to login page.

Here is simple counter number save example:

```
_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Retriving data
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  //Saving data
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

there are prefs.setString/ pref.manymore to save, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Youre my saviour hahaha

Comment: glad to help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

[LoginPage Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuwIX.png)

[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxn3A.png)

This is how i am setting Data in Shared Preferences during UserLogin

```
          UserID = firebaseuser.uid;
          UserName = firebaseuser.displayName;
          UserPhoto = firebaseuser.photoURL;
          UserEmail = firebaseuser.email;
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          prefs.setString('UserID', UserID);
          prefs.setString('UserEmail', UserEmail);
          prefs.setString('UserName', UserName);
          prefs.setString('UserPhoto', UserPhoto);`
```

And here i am checking whether UserId named shared Preferences data exists or not , if exists then user is logged In if not then User is not logged In to the App

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
SharedPreferences prefs;

Future<void> main() async {
 
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 String UserID = prefs.getString('UserID');
 String UserName = prefs.getString('UserName');
 String UserEmail = prefs.getString('UserEmail');
 String UserPhoto = prefs.getString('UserPhoto');
 runApp(
 
     MaterialApp(
         home: UserID == null
             ? App()
             :
           
             MyApp(
                 UserID: UserID,
                 UserName: UserName,
                 UserEmail: UserEmail,
                 UserPhoto: UserPhoto,
               )));
}`





Like this You can check whether the user is signed in or not. If signed In u can return
a different screen and if not then a different one
```